# Declare a variable class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need to declare a variable class in my code so i can access a function (having the same name in all classes) but doing each time a different behavior).

and this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Bubble : ItemBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        theclass.Behaviour ();
    }
}
```

knowing that  (theclass gonna be variable ).

---

Thank you guys for your answer but it is a bit special.

My game is about interaction between player and game objects when the player approach any item that is "interactible" lets say, a bubble shows up, this bubble is a GameObject and it is the same for any object that allow interactions,

So since i am doing a 2D game i thought, it would be great if i make a "universal"
 EmptyGameObject that contains all common aspects that anyObject would contain, and i grouped main functions and common ones in a general script and i added it to this emptyGameObject, then i added the Bubble prefab to this Game object and i a dded a code to it this code contains what i wrote in my firs post.

i was thinking that now each time i want an object i just drop this emptygameobject prefab and changes sprites and characteristics.

And each object have a different behavior (ex: i can delete an apple as if the character consumed it but i can not consume a door, the door would rather trigger an animation than being destructed ) i am specifying all this in a class for each item.

now whatever the class is (the object is) the trigger is in the bubble class (which i posted first) but the class will be different each time and i can not make a class that contains polymorphism because its not the same context each time.

Comment: So your question is how to pass in a variable into the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709315/passing-variables-from-main-function-to-another-c-sharp-class.

Comment: no not to pass variables between classes but to have a type class that its class changes according to what i add in the inspector, and any class that would be added contains the "Behaviour()" function that i developed when i was creating it... 
so i am sure of the Behaviour() function but the class may change and i don't know how am i gonna have as classes because each object i will be creating for the game will contain a NameBehaviour.cd class and contain this function.

Comment: The very first sentence for the tag [tag:Unity] is **"DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)!!"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,

The matter was solved by creating a global (abstract) gameOject that contains the class that we want to inherit from, and then each time the gameObject atached to this class calls (Behavior function) it trigger whatever the override is for this function for this object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create an interface that declares all the functions you would like to use in different classes.

```
interface IBehaviour
{
   void Behaviour();
   void AnotherBehaviour();
}
```

with this you define a behaviour what a class, which implements the interface, is capable of.

And then your classes would be:

```
class MyClass1 : Ibehaviour
{
}

class MyClass2 : IBehaviour
{
}
```

Apart from this you can use abstract classes. There are a lot of well-written articles about these topics on the Internet.

Firstly, I recommend to get familiar with OOP principles.
[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/object-oriented-programming-using-C-Sharp-net/) link is a good way to start.

Good luck.