# How can pass textBox value to another class

Tags: c#

Can i press the textbox value to class file

Windows Form :

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Staffid = Staffid_txt.Text;
            string Pwd = Pwd_txt.Text;
            dbConnect.UserAuthCommd();
```

dbConnect:

```
     public ConnectDB()
{
    Initialize();
}
.   
.
.
public void UserAuthCommd()
```

I don't know  how can i  get  Staffid , Pwd  into dbConnect and use staffid and pwd to SQL query

Comment: Try This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709315/passing-variables-from-main-function-to-another-c-sharp-class

Answer (score 2):

If the `UserAuthCommd` method needs string values, then have it accept string values:

```
public void UserAuthCommd(string staffId, string password)
{
    //...
}
```

And pass it the values when you invoke it:

```
dbConnect.UserAuthCommd(Staffid_txt.Text, Pwd_txt.Text);
```